# Plumbing vent for new addition

Tags: plumbing, venting

I am turning an old 1 car garage into a master bathroom and laundry room. I'm unclear as to the way to vent the new plumbing. I'll explain the layout first.

I'm standing in the middle of the wall in the laundry room with my back against the existing house. The main trunk of the plumbing is immediately behind and below me. To my right and a little in front of me is the washer. About 8 feet in front of me is the sink in the master. Just to the right of the sink is the shower. Just past the shower, on the right and a little farther from me is the toilet.

From me to the toilet is about 16'. Above me and to my left is the upstairs toilet. That vents to the main vent which is 6' behind me.

My plan is to run a vent line in the wall that separates the master bathroom and the laundry room. I was planning on running that up to the attic and then running it horizontal to tie into the existing vent so I don't have to put another hole in the roof.

I was planning to tie into the vent just before the sink and shower tie into the main trunk. Are there any problems with this plan?

Comment: A sketch would do wonders here. It's hard to accurately build your design in our minds.

Comment: 1. You need a drawing. 2. Get that drawing in front of whatever official is going to inspect your work for your permit.